# Python: What kind of syntax is it to use for after a statement in side a function?

Tags: python

I saw a line of code to generate random string.

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(N))
```

I am not sure what type of usage is this and I cannot find it in python doc.

I try

```
random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(N)
```

but it says there's a syntax error

Comment: Your syntax error can be easily solved by turning it into either a list comprehension (wrap it in `[]`) or a generator (wrap in `()`).

Comment: Also related: [list comprehension without \[ \], Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9060653)

Answer (score 1):

It's a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

> The semantics of a generator expression are equivalent to creating an anonymous generator function and calling it. For example:
>
> ```
> g = (x**2 for x in range(10))
> print g.next()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def __gen(exp):
>     for x in exp:
>         yield x**2
> g = __gen(iter(range(10)))
> print g.next()
> ```

Comment: And, notably, *generators* are *iterable*, like lists. So you can call [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on them just like on a list.